# Connecting Vaadin project and Spring Boot project

Tags: spring-boot, vaadin

I have one vaadin project and one Spring Boot project. Is there anyway such that i can connect them or call/import one project into the other?

Comment: Please clarify what each one does and what you mean by `call/import`, like do you want to have only one application where you integrate the Spring project into the Vaadin one (or vice-versa), or does the Spring project export some kind of service (soap, rest, etc) that the Vaadin one should consume?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Lets say i have a Vaadin project with UI in which i enter data. I have a Spring Boot  project which needs the data entered in the Vaadin to perform operations. How can i connect them?

Comment: Sounds like you want one application with Vaadin and Spring. You can get some inspiration from the Vaadin [official tutorial for integration with Spring](http://vaadin.github.io/spring-tutorial/). Go over the docs, try to apply what you've learned and let us know if you have issues.